# Any maximal subgroups of a finite group are conjugate then G is cyclic.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite group G, if G satisfies the property that any two maximal subgroups are conjugate, G is cyclic. I was thinking about Sylow theorem which states that for finite group and prime factor p, any Sylow p-subgroups are conjugate. I wish to somehow use that result to show G has order a prime number, thus cyclic. However, I am, at the moment, clueless. Any help or guide is greatly appreciated =).

Comment: @David Hill, would you mind explaining further why is that ?

Comment: @Thiet Look at the maximal subgroups of the group of quaternions. If you pick any pair, are they conjugate?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272977/finite-group-such-that-any-two-maximal-subgroups-are-conjugate-is-cyclic), and the solution in the comments.